# I can't install a go package

Tags: go, package

i'm currently try to install https://github.com/willnorris/imageproxy . I'm a newbie with go lang. So i installed first go, github and hg.

I tried a few things, clone the git repository, use go get, use go install, go build.
But nothing worked, it could download the files to the src direcotry, but didn't get the bin.

so has anybody an idea?

---edit---
with:
go get github.com/willnorris/imageproxy/cmd/imageproxy

i get:

```
[root@s17848415 go]# go get github.com/willnorris/imageproxy/cmd/imageproxy
# github.com/willnorris/imageproxy/cmd/imageproxy
src/github.com/willnorris/imageproxy/cmd/imageproxy/main.go:27: imported and not used: "github.com/sosedoff/imageproxy/proxy"
src/github.com/willnorris/imageproxy/cmd/imageproxy/main.go:60: undefined: imageproxy
```

--edit 2 ---

```
[root@s17848415 go]# go get github.com/willnorris/imageproxy/cmd/imageproxy
package willnorris.com/go/imageproxy: unrecognized import path "willnorris.com/go/imageproxy"
```

Comment: In particular, please be very specific about what commands you executed.  e.g. did you do: *go get github.com/willnorris/imageproxy/cmd/imageproxy*, or something else?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling github? :)

Answer (score 1):

solution:

first:

```
go get github.com/willnorris/imageproxy/cmd/imageproxy
```

(downloads source)

second - change "vi github.com/willnorris/imageproxy/cmd/imageproxy"
last line

```
import (
     "flag"
     "fmt"
     "log"
     "net/http"
     "strings"

     "github.com/gregjones/httpcache"
     "github.com/gregjones/httpcache/diskcache"

     "github.com/willnorris/imageproxy"
 )
```

last - again:

```
  go get github.com/willnorris/imageproxy/cmd/imageproxy
```

Answer (score 1):

I've updated the README file to include getting started instructions: https://github.com/willnorris/imageproxy#getting-started.  Notably, you should go get as "willnorris.com/go/imageproxy", not "github.com/willnorris/imageproxy".